# How to replace a number with NA in R but add the replaced number to a different variable?

Tags: r, row

I have some data:

```
set.seed(565)
df <- data.frame(rs1 = rnorm(100, mean = 50, sd = 3), rs2 = rnorm(100, mean = 4, sd = 0.2), rs3 = rnorm(100, mean = 15, sd = 1),
                 rs4 = rnorm(100, mean = 2, sd = 0.04))
```

I want to replace any number less than 3 in this dataframe with NA, but make sure that the number that was replaced is added to the variable with the highest number in that row (so the row total does not change).
E.G. for row 1, which looks like:

```
50.92756   4.033628   14.36690   1.999160
```

after the command should look like:

```
52.92672   4.033628   14.36690   NA
```

Comment: what if all the values in a row are less than 3?

Comment: @onyambu - all NA

Comment: Then where do you add them to?

Comment: @onyambu if all instances are less than 3 (which will be extremely unlikely) then the whole row can be NA.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R way.

```r
set.seed(565)
df <- data.frame(rs1 = rnorm(100, mean = 50, sd = 3), rs2 = rnorm(100, mean = 4, sd = 0.2), rs3 = rnorm(100, mean = 15, sd = 1),
                 rs4 = rnorm(100, mean = 2, sd = 0.04))


df[] <- t(apply(df, 1, \(x) {
  i <- which.max(x)
  j <- x < 3
  if(any(j)) {
    x[i] <- x[i] + sum(x[which(j)])
    is.na(x) <- j
  }
  x
}))
head(df, n = 10)
#>         rs1      rs2      rs3 rs4
#> 1  52.92672 4.033628 14.36690  NA
#> 2  52.82045 4.088581 12.49494  NA
#> 3  53.94117 3.635854 15.17427  NA
#> 4  49.97355 4.076953 15.06030  NA
#> 5  53.17885 4.020831 13.92384  NA
#> 6  55.86003 4.064562 14.37932  NA
#> 7  51.34426 4.163213 14.22895  NA
#> 8  56.79130 4.029414 14.90220  NA
#> 9  52.20528 4.135510 15.69041  NA
#> 10 52.70072 4.250440 15.14747  NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks - what is my first column is of character? The code will fail, is there a way to add a condition to skip character columns or the first column?

Comment: @krtbris Yes, there is, `df[-1] <- t(apply(df[-1], etc))`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this will work whether all the row is less than 3 or not

```
idx <- cbind(seq(nrow(df)), max.col(df))
df[idx] <- df[idx] * NA ^ (df[idx] < 3)+ rowSums(df * (df < 3))
is.na(df) <- df < 3
df

        rs1      rs2      rs3 rs4
1   52.92672 4.033628 14.36690  NA
2   52.82045 4.088581 12.49494  NA
3   53.94117 3.635854 15.17427  NA
4   49.97355 4.076953 15.06030  NA
5   53.17885 4.020831 13.92384  NA
6   55.86003 4.064562 14.37932  NA
7   51.34426 4.163213 14.22895  NA
8   56.79130 4.029414 14.90220  NA
```

Comment: Thanks - what is my first column is of character? The code will fail, is there a way to add a condition to skip character columns or the first column?

Comment: @krtbris just remove that particular column. ie strat with `a <- df[-1]` then in the above code, change `df` to `a` then at the end have `cbind(df[1], a)`. or simply every place i have `df` write `df[-1]`

Answer (score -1):

Something like this would work.

```
set.seed(565)

df <- data.frame(rs1 = rnorm(100, mean = 50, sd = 3), rs2 = rnorm(100, mean = 4, sd = 0.2), rs3 = rnorm(100, mean = 15, sd = 1),
                 rs4 = rnorm(100, mean = 2, sd = 0.04))

min_index <- df == apply(df, 2, \(x) x <= 3)

max_index <- df == apply(df, 1, max)

df[max_index] <- df[max_index] + df[min_index]

df[min_index] <- NA

df

#         rs1      rs2      rs3 rs4
#1   52.92672 4.033628 14.36690  NA
#2   52.82045 4.088581 12.49494  NA
```

Comment: I am not sure you have followed the question. I don't want to produce NA's just in column 4. It is in any column for any number less than 3. I just used the first row as an example with column 4 having a value less than 3.

Comment: Sorry I misread. Edited to reflect that.

Comment: This will also only work if there is only 1 value less than 3.